# JSON.parse unexpected result in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am sending a http request to a website (from node.js) which returns a JSON object. I get the expected JSON file. However when I parse the JSON text, my program isn't able to do anything.

```
var URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + movie + '&y=&plot=short&r=json';
requestify.get(URL).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.getBody()); // It prints correctly
    var jsonBody =  response.getBody();
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
    if (jsonObject.Response == 'False') {
        console.log('False'); //not printed
    } else {
        console.log('true'); //Not printed
    }
});
```

Sample JSON output:

```
{"Response":"False","Error":"Movie not found!"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.body` is the raw text response. [`response.getBody()`](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify/blob/v0.2.0/lib/response.js#L36) should already return a parsed JSON response as long as you have the correct `content-type` header specified.

Sending a JS object to `JSON.parse` results in a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @CORY I missed out that line while copying from my code. I have done that and it hasn't worked

Comment: @CORY This is on server side (node.js) I am using chrome browser btw.

Comment: Yeah I just realized this was tagged with node.js. No script errors or anything? The `JSON` library is built in to node so I don't see why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: FYI `response.body` is the raw text response. `response.getBody()` should already return a parsed JSON response.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just checked that before you put your comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1692342: I updated my answer and removed the irrelevant suggestions. Glad to help.